# linq xml child elements/nodes

Tags: xml, linq

I have xml document:

```
<users>
        <user_tuple>
          <userid>U01</userid>
          <code>
            <name>Tom Jones</name>
          </code>
          <rating>B</rating>
        </user_tuple>
        <user_tuple>
          <userid>U02</userid>
          <code>
             <name>Mary Doe</name>
          </code>
          <rating>A</rating>
        </user_tuple>
        <user_tuple>
          <userid>U03</userid>
          <code>
            <name>Dee Linquent</name>
          </code>
         <rating>D</rating>
        </user_tuple>
```

How do I select only those   (and all child nodes/elements) where userid.Value== "U01" and rating.Value=="B" etc
ie I want results:

```
 <user_tuple>
      <userid>U01</userid>
      <code>
        <name>Tom Jones</name>
      </code>
      <rating>B</rating>
    </user_tuple>
```

Answer (score 0):

This should work (in C#), try it out

```
string id = "U01";
string rating = "B";
XDocument doc = null;
using (var reader1 = new StreamReader(@"..\..\test.xml"))
{
  doc = XDocument.Load(reader1);
  var nodes = from c in doc.Descendants("user_tuple")
                           .Where(d => d.Element("userid").Value == id && d.Element("rating").Value == rating)
              select c;
}
```

Comment: Thnx. And if select x.Element("userid").Value == "U01" and x.Element("name").Value == "Tom Jones" ?

Answer (score 0):

You only need values where Userid and rating matches. Here is the code

```
XElement root = XElement.Load(@"YOUR XML PATH");
        var res = root.Elements("user_tuple").Where(x => x.Element("userid").Value == "U01" && x.Element("rating").Value == "B").Elements();
```

Comment: Use namespace **System.XML.Linq**

Comment: Thnx. And if select  x.Element("userid").Value == "U01" and x.Element("name").Value == "Tom Jones" ?

Comment: @ГарикГарик You will get the same